# JavaScript: infinite loop, or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-loop

In my function I'm looping through a tree looking for a specific attribute in a node. The function is called recursively and stops when the attribute is found or when there are no more nodes in the tree.

However when I run the function it goes into what I assume is an infinite loop, Firefox freezes and I have to stop the process. Then I added a `setTimeout` to the function in order to determine what was causing the problem, but now the whole thing runs correctly. I'm posting the function here if anyone has some insight to what the issue is (btw I'm using AngularJS and unchecking a checkbox):

```
$scope.uncheckNode = function(nodeId, subitem){
        // Loop through each node in the sub nodes
        for (i = 0; i<subitem.length; i++){
            // If the node is found, uncheck it and break from the loop
            if (subitem[i].Id == nodeId){
                subitem[i].selected = false;
                break;
            }
            // Otherwise get the sub nodes of the subnodes
            // (an empty array if undefined)
            // Check if it has any nodes and continue with the recursion
            else{
                var subsubitem = subitem[i].Subitem || [];

                if (subsubitem.length > 0){
                   $scope.uncheckNode(nodeId, subsubitem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will infinitely loop if it never finds `nodeId` in the subitems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you're using a global `i` variable. Because you haven't declared it, you're falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*. So when the function calls itself, it resets the global `i` to `0`. If the subordinate call returns (because there are no subitems), `i` will be whatever its last value was in the subordinate call. If that's less than it was in the calling code, you'll loop forever.

To make `i` a local variable, add a `var i` to the function.

---

You might consider using strict mode by adding `"use strict"` at the top of your code. In strict mode, you don't have implicit globals anymore, you have a nice clear `ReferenceError` reminding you to add the declaration instead..